# Windows 10 file boot sequence?

Tags: windows-10, boot, desktop-computer

I cannot for the life of me find a list of files Windows 10 needs in order to boot up. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide some context?  Are you just curious or do you need to fix something?  Are you talking about the bare minimum to boot or a typical installation or your customized system?  Are you looking for instructions on how to view the bootloader?

Comment: Windows 10 uses a more complex bootloader than Windows XP. Typing `msconfig` in run can do simple changes.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a long time ago, so I'm not sure if you're still seeking for an answer, but I'll just answer it.

The files used depend on whether your computer boots in Legacy mode or UEFI mode. If it uses Legacy, then the BIOS starts the file "bootmgr", located at the root of the partition marked as "active" (usually the System Reserved partition), which eventually starts C:\Windows\System32\winload.exe. Winload.exe loads the Operating System.

If your computer is configured to boot in UEFI mode, then the UEFI triggers the file \EFI\Microsoft\boot\bootmgfw.efi, located on the EFI-partition (ESP). This file then runs C:\Windows\System32\winload.efi (note the extension), which will load the OS.

Extra info: the files needed for the UEFI itself are located in \EFI\Boot. And if you're not sure if your system uses Legacy BIOS or UEFI, open msinfo.exe and look at BIOS Mode. Next to it you'll find the answer.

I hope this answered your questions. Feel free to ask for further clarifications if you need to.